# What is the best way to create a prefab object in Unity with a randomly generated mesh?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, prefab

I have been working my way through quill18's hex-based civ-style game coding [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-rCuN7uMR8&list=PLbghT7MmckI7JHf0pdEQ8fbPb-LoDXEno) for Unity. As I finish up the series, I'm trying my hand at generating random meshes rather than just using meshes imported from Blender. I've managed to write some code that randomly generates a mountain hex tile with a single peak.

[image: My randomly generated mountain hex]

However, I'm not sure how to attach it to a prefab object in Unity. The way the tutorial works, Unity creates a clone of a prefab object for every single tile. From what I've read, this seems to be best practice, especially for more complicated projects. So this leads to my question: how do I create a prefab object with a randomly generated mesh? If this can't be done, what is the correct/best practice way of implementing this?

Comment: Just to b sure: By `prefab` you refer to an actual **prefab asset** => created in edit time you want to save and use in the editor, rather than to an **instance** of a GameObject in the scene, right?

Comment: Not entirely sure how useful a _prefab_ is when _no two look alike._

Comment: No @derHugo I don't plan on using the editor to update the mesh at all. I want to generate a new mountain model for every tile and then use that with the game object. I only used the term prefab because that's how the tutorial structured the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone not only the prefabs, but also the gameObjects in the scene directly.
I guess it uses the Instantiate () function.
With this function, just enter the generated object as parameter "original" and it will be duplicated.
Implied instead of having a public field to which you assign the prefab to then be duplicated, you can do the same thing without assigning the prefab but only with the generated object.